# Need to Change DNS to get Gmail to Speed UP

Tags: email, dns, gmail, ip, email-client

I'm having an odd problem with gmail.  My gmail is painfully, excruciatingly sluggish.  Messages take a long while to load, send, frequent "#717" errors, etc.  I realize that this is [a rather common frustration](http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2010/05/gmail-has-become-unsuably-slow.html) and I have tried all the [standard cures](http://www.techfeb.com/2011/03/open-your-gmail-fast-if-you-hurry/) that people recommend.

I have found, however, that changing my computer's DNS settings often temporarily fixes the problem.  The change doesn't have to be to any particular IP, it just has to be to *some* different IP.  I usually toggle between Google's two public IPv4 DNS IPs (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).  Let's say I'm on the former at the moment and gmail is currently hanging while it loads a message.  I open my network preferences and [change to the latter](http://cl.ly/image/3S211c2D3z35), and the minute I hit "apply" Gmail *instantly* loads the message.  This has happened many times; it is clearly repeatable.  I have suggested that friends also try it, and they have seen the same effect.

So, two questions:

1. What would cause this behavior?
2. Is there anything I can do to automatically/programatically accomplish this so that I don't have to frequently manually toggle my DNS?

Comment: You say you "toggle between Google's two public IPv4 DNS IPs" - you should be specifying _both_ at the same time as the primary and secondary DNS. ?

Comment: Trying to accomplish this automatically is the wrong solution. It is as if you drive a car on a highway and the motor stalls every 5 minutes. Your solution would be to stop and restart the car automatically.  Finding out what is wrong would be better.

Comment: @w3d if I do that, then OS X always uses the first entry and the effect of the "toggling" doesn't occur.

Comment: @Hennes agree 100%, I've just been using it as a poor stopgap.  I'd love to find the root cause of this.

Comment: Can you try adding gmails IPs to your OS's version of /etc/host and see if that helps? (and no, that is not a proper solution either, but it might work and it might yield additional clues as to what is wrong)

Comment: Interesting. I have been using Gmail for a few years now and have so far not experienced the slow down you mention. Nor can I repeat the issue, that your friends seem to be able to do, using your suggestion. The "standard cures" you link to are just generic speed-up tips for those on a slow connection - these should not be necessary IMO. I wonder if it's a regional thing - presumably your friends are all in the same locality? Do they all use Macs? How full is your inbox? That other user cites 4GB as a trigger. Must admit I am using less than 1GB.

Comment: @w3d Yes, I think the slowness is almost certainly associated with inbox size.  I have bought extra storage from Google, so on a percentage basis the inbox isn't slow, but I do have over 11GB in there.  I've already gone to great pains to prune that down (including using [FindBigMail](https://www.findbigmail.com/) but unfortunately it's hard for met to get it much lower than that.

Comment: @Hennes do you mean the IPs associated with gmail.com?  Do you think there would be many of those (and that they would change frequently)?

Comment: Possibly. But if they stay stable for a while and the problem goes away while you use a hosts file rather than a resolver look up then you would have additional information. -- Right now I have no idea *why* something goes wrong. Finding out what (and more specific than 'something within DNS) might help to actually solve this.